# Is there a problem with my cucumber in the terminal?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

I'm running into a couple issues with my app. I'm following this tutorial.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-web-apps-with-capybara-and-cucumber--net-21446

As far as I'm concerned I have followed the tutorial to a T. But when i go to run the code using the cucumber keyword in my windows CMD, it throws the following error.

```
Feature: Viewer visits the Home Page
    In order to read the Page
    As a Viewer
    I want to see the home page of my app

  Scenario: View home page                     # features/home_page.feature:6
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.10.2/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:965:in `method_missing': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:205:in `stringify_namespaced_modules'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:169:in `inspect'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:121:in `inspect'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:126:in `to_s'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:53:in `rescue in execute!'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:24:in `execute!'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/bin/cucumber:25:in `load'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/bin/cucumber:25:in `<main>'
E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.10.2/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:965:in `method_missing': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:205:in `stringify_namespaced_modules'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:169:in `inspect'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:121:in `inspect'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/glue/proto_world.rb:126:in `to_s'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:54:in `handlers_for'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `broadcast'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:40:in `method_missing'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:37:in `around_hook'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:12:in `describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:81:in `compose_around_hooks'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:29:in `block in describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:19:in `test_case'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:57:in `test_case'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/retry.rb:18:in `test_case'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:21:in `block in done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `map'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:20:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:31:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:46:in `done'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:35:in `parse'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-10.1.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:83:in `run!'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/bin/cucumber:25:in `load'
        from E:/Ruby30-x64/bin/cucumber:25:in `<main>'
```

Is there something wrong with my cucumber gem? or is it another issue? If you'd like I can also post the rest of my code it was just a few files. Help?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you’re following is from 11 years ago. My guess is just that the tutorial is massively out of date.

Comment: I guess that could be right. I didn’t realize that. I just can’t seem to find any more up to date for those three frameworks and languages. But I appreciate the help. 